# Sorting string array in c

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, char

I have a collection of strings of planet names in c. I have stored them in a character array. I want to sort them out. I know there's a string comparing method in c but I need to implement mine. In my method(`string_compare(char *planet1, char *planet2)`), i check characters between two planets. If character of planet1 is after that of plannet2, then I return 1, else 0 is returned. I then rearrange the array items accordingly. At the moment, my loop is not exiting. It is running infinetely. I am also having trouble exchanging the array entries. Please assist.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <string.h>

//method declaration
int string_compare(char *planet1, char *planet2);

//main method
int main () {
    char *planets[9]= {"Mercury", "Venus", "Earth", "Mars", "Jupiter", "Saturn", "Uranus", "Neptune", "Pluto"};
    bool sorted=false;

    int i=0, count = 0;
    do{
    int planets_size = (int)sizeof(planets)/sizeof(planets[0]);
    for(i=0; i< planets_size-1;i++){
        char *planet1_pointer = planets[i];
        char *planet2_pointer = planets[i+1];
        int comparison = string_compare(planet1_pointer,planet2_pointer);
        if(comparison>1){
                planets[i] = planet2_pointer;
                planets[i+1] = planet1_pointer;
                sorted = false;
                break;
            } else {
                if(i==planets_size-1){
                    sorted = true;
                }
            }
        }
        count++;
    } while (sorted==false);
    printf("The planets in alphabetical order are ");
    //printf("%s",planets);

    i=0;
    for (i=0; i<9; i++) {
        printf("%s " , planets[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}

int string_compare(char *planet1, char *planet2){
    int planet1_size = strlen(planet1);
    int planet2_size = strlen(planet2);
    int size=0;

    if(planet1_size<planet2_size){
        size = planet1_size;
    } else{
        size = planet2_size;
    }

    int i=0;
    for(i=0; i < size;i++){
        if((int)planet1[i]<(int)planet2[i]){
            return 0;
        } else if((int)planet1[i]>(int)planet2[i]){
            return 1;
        } else {
            continue;
        }
    }

return 0;
}
```

My code is above. I am a beginner in c.

Comment: When you use `sizeof` on a pointer, you only get the size of the *pointer* and not what it points to. To get the length of the string, either use `strlen`, or if you must make the code yourself (as an exercise) remember that strings in C are terminated by the character `'\0'`.

Comment: `if(i==planets_size){` Never be true.

Comment: for ease of understanding and readability by us humans: 1) separate code blocks (for, if, else, while, do... while, switch, case, default) via a blank line.  2) follow the axiom: *only one statement per line and (at most) one variable declaration per statement.  3) consistently indent the code.  indent after every opening brace '{'.  unindent before every closing brace '}. do not use tabs for indenting.  Suggest 4 spaces for each indent level.

Comment: the posted code is trying to combine a `for()` loop with a `do... while()` loop.  that will not work, the result is the `for()` loop is run to completion.  the the `while()` loop is entered (and if entered, never exits.

Comment: please explain why you could not use the `strcmp()` function instead of writing the `string_compare()` function.

Comment: the sorting functionality built into the `main()` function does not actually sort the array.  Suggest google for 'bubble sort algorithm in c'  and incorporating the resulting code into your program.

Comment: the posted code exits the `for()` loop (that is trying to sort the array) if the array is not already sorted.  Why?  Also, note that the strings in the `planets[]` array will be located in readonly memory, so they cannot be actually sorted (however, the pointers in the array to the actual strings can be sorted.

Answer (score 1):

You looped using `for(i=0; i< planets_size-1;i++)`. Notice the **`i< planets_size-1`**, so the condition `if(i==planets_size-1)` will always be false since `i` will be always less than `planets_size-1` by the definition of your for loop (in other words never equal).

Answer (score 1):

There are two issues with the code. One of them, as pointed out by others, is that `if(i==planets_size-1)` in the main function will never be true because in the `for` loop you will not be going beyond `planets_size-2`.

Another issue is that `if(comparison>1)` will never be true either because the `string_compare` function returns either 0 or 1.